# Count ROW type item Athena / Presto

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

I have an Athena query like this

```sql
SELECT typeof(records)
FROM "default"."table"
WHERE date = '2021-07-24'
AND device_id = 'abc'
```

and the result is

```
_col0
row(1579560177000 row(ab decimal(38,9), bc  decimal(38,9), cd decimal(38,9), de decimal(38,9), ef decimal(38,9), fg decimal(38,9), gh decimal(38,9), hi decimal(38,9), ij decimal(38,9), jk decimal(38,9)), 1579518772000 row(ds decimal(38,9)), 1579529572000 row(ds decimal(38,9)), 1579554776000 row(ab decimal(38,9), bc  decimal(38,9), cd decimal(38,9), de decimal(38,9), ef decimal(38,9), fg decimal(38,9), gh decimal(38,9), hi decimal(38,9), ij decimal(38,9), jk decimal(38,9)), 1579556575000 row(ab decimal(38,9), bc  decimal(38,9), cd decimal(38,9), de decimal(38,9), ef decimal(38,9), fg decimal(38,9), gh decimal(38,9), hi decimal(38,9), ij decimal(38,9), jk decimal(38,9)), 1579517872000 row(ds decimal(38,9)), 1579547574000 row(ab decimal(38,9), bc  decimal(38,9), cd decimal(38,9), de decimal(38,9), ef decimal(38,9), fg decimal(38,9), gh decimal(38,9), hi decimal(38,9), ij decimal(38,9), jk decimal(38,9)), 1579525072000 row(ds decimal(38,9)), 1579551176000 row(ab decimal(38,9), bc  decimal(38,9), cd decimal(38,9), de decimal(38,9), ef decimal(38,9), fg decimal(38,9), gh decimal(38,9), hi decimal(38,9), ij decimal(38,9), jk decimal(38,9)), 1579555676000 row(ab decimal(38,9), bc  decimal(38,9), cd decimal(38,9), de decimal(38,9), ef decimal(38,9), fg decimal(38,9), gh decimal(38,9), hi decimal(38,9), ij decimal(38,9), jk decimal(38,9)), 1579540372000 row(ab decimal(38,9), bc  decimal(38,9), cd decimal(38,9), de decimal(38,9), ef decimal(38,9), fg decimal(38,9), gh decimal(38,9), hi decimal(38,9), ij decimal(38,9), jk decimal(38,9)), 1579564676000 row(ds decimal(38,9)), 1579548475000 row(ab decimal(38,9), bc  decimal(38,9), cd decimal(38,9), de decimal(38,9), ef decimal(38,9), fg decimal(38,9), gh decimal(38,9), hi decimal(38,9), ij decimal(38,9), jk decimal(38,9)), 1579530472000 row(ds decimal(38,9)), 1579528672000 row(ds decimal(38,9)), 1579552076000 row(ab decimal(38,9), bc  decimal(38,9), cd decimal(38,9), de decimal(38,9), ef decimal(38,9), fg decimal(38,9), gh decimal(38,9), hi decimal(38,9), ij decimal(38,9), jk decimal(38,9)), 1579516072000 row(ds decimal(38,9)), 1579519672000 row(ds decimal(38,9)), 1579520572000 row(ds decimal(38,9)), 1579561076000 row(ab decimal(38,9), bc  decimal(38,9), cd decimal(38,9), de decimal(38,9), ef decimal(38,9), fg decimal(38,9), gh decimal(38,9), hi decimal(38,9), ij decimal(38,9), jk decimal(38,9)), 1579535872000 row(ds decimal(38,9)), 1579544873000 row(ab decimal(38,9), bc  decimal(38,9), cd decimal(38,9), de decimal(38,9), ef decimal(38,9), fg decimal(38,9), gh decimal(38,9), hi decimal(38,9), ij decimal(38,9), jk decimal(38,9)), 1579557476000 row(ab decimal(38,9), bc  decimal(38,9), cd decimal(38,9), de decimal(38,9), ef decimal(38,9), fg decimal(38,9), gh decimal(38,9), hi decimal(38,9), ij decimal(38,9), jk decimal(38,9)), 1579561976000 row(ab decimal(38,9), bc  decimal(38,9), cd decimal(38,9), de decimal(38,9), ef decimal(38,9), fg decimal(38,9), gh decimal(38,9), hi decimal(38,9), ij decimal(38,9), jk decimal(38,9)), 1579546674000 row(ab decimal(38,9), bc  decimal(38,9), cd decimal(38,9), de decimal(38,9), ef decimal(38,9), fg decimal(38,9), gh decimal(38,9), hi decimal(38,9), ij decimal(38,9), jk decimal(38,9)), 1579516972000 row(ds decimal(38,9)), 1579523272000 row(ds decimal(38,9)), 1579538572000 row(ab decimal(38,9), bc  decimal(38,9), cd decimal(38,9), de decimal(38,9), ef decimal(38,9), fg decimal(38,9), gh decimal(38,9), hi decimal(38,9), ij decimal(38,9), jk decimal(38,9)), 1579525972000 row(ds decimal(38,9)), 1579542173000 row(ab decimal(38,9), bc  decimal(38,9), cd decimal(38,9), de decimal(38,9), ef decimal(38,9), fg decimal(38,9), gh decimal(38,9), hi decimal(38,9), ij decimal(38,9), jk decimal(38,9)), 1579559276000 row(ab decimal(38,9), bc  decimal(38,9), cd decimal(38,9), de decimal(38,9), ef decimal(38,9), fg decimal(38,9), gh decimal(38,9), hi decimal(38,9), ij decimal(38,9), jk decimal(38,9)), 1579521472000 row(ds decimal(38,9)), 1579522372000 row(ds decimal(38,9)), 1579533172000 row(ds decimal(38,9)), 1579537672000 row(ds decimal(38,9)), 1579526872000 row(ds decimal(38,9)), 1579562876000 row(ds decimal(38,9)), 1579545773000 row(ab decimal(38,9), bc  decimal(38,9), cd decimal(38,9), de decimal(38,9), ef decimal(38,9), fg decimal(38,9), gh decimal(38,9), hi decimal(38,9), ij decimal(38,9), jk decimal(38,9)), 1579550275000 row(ab decimal(38,9), bc  decimal(38,9), cd decimal(38,9), de decimal(38,9), ef decimal(38,9), fg decimal(38,9), gh decimal(38,9), hi decimal(38,9), ij decimal(38,9), jk decimal(38,9)), 1579558376000 row(ab decimal(38,9), bc  decimal(38,9), cd decimal(38,9), de decimal(38,9), ef decimal(38,9), fg decimal(38,9), gh decimal(38,9), hi decimal(38,9), ij decimal(38,9), jk decimal(38,9)), 1579532272000 row(ds decimal(38,9)), 1579536772000 row(ds decimal(38,9)), 1579549375000 row(ab decimal(38,9), bc  decimal(38,9), cd decimal(38,9), de decimal(38,9), ef decimal(38,9), fg decimal(38,9), gh decimal(38,9), hi decimal(38,9), ij decimal(38,9), jk decimal(38,9)), 1579552976000 row(ab decimal(38,9), bc  decimal(38,9), cd decimal(38,9), de decimal(38,9), ef decimal(38,9), fg decimal(38,9), gh decimal(38,9), hi decimal(38,9), ij decimal(38,9), jk decimal(38,9)), 1579563776000 row(ds decimal(38,9)), 1579524172000 row(ds decimal(38,9)), 1579543973000 row(ab decimal(38,9), bc  decimal(38,9), cd decimal(38,9), de decimal(38,9), ef decimal(38,9), fg decimal(38,9), gh decimal(38,9), hi decimal(38,9), ij decimal(38,9), jk decimal(38,9)), 1579553876000 row(ab decimal(38,9), bc  decimal(38,9), cd decimal(38,9), de decimal(38,9), ef decimal(38,9), fg decimal(38,9), gh decimal(38,9), hi decimal(38,9), ij decimal(38,9), jk decimal(38,9)), 1579534972000 row(ds decimal(38,9)), 1579539472000 row(ab decimal(38,9), bc  decimal(38,9), cd decimal(38,9), de decimal(38,9), ef decimal(38,9), fg decimal(38,9), gh decimal(38,9), hi decimal(38,9), ij decimal(38,9), jk decimal(38,9)), 1579541272000 row(ab decimal(38,9), bc  decimal(38,9), cd decimal(38,9), de decimal(38,9), ef decimal(38,9), fg decimal(38,9), gh decimal(38,9), hi decimal(38,9), ij decimal(38,9), jk decimal(38,9)), 1579543073000 row(ab decimal(38,9), bc  decimal(38,9), cd decimal(38,9), de decimal(38,9), ef decimal(38,9), fg decimal(38,9), gh decimal(38,9), hi decimal(38,9), ij decimal(38,9), jk decimal(38,9)), 1579531372000 row(ds decimal(38,9)), 1579527772000 row(ds decimal(38,9)), 1579534072000 row(ds decimal(38,9)))
```

I would like to count the number of records per day per devices to have a result like this

```
device_id, date, recordsNb
abc, 2021-07-24, 37
```

EDIT

My dataset is actually like this

```
device_id, date, records
abc, 2021-07-24, {"1": {}, "2":{}}
def, 2021-07-24, {"a": {}, "b":{}, "c": {}}
```

Here the expected results would be :

```
device_id, date, recordsNb
abc, 2021-07-24, 2
def, 2021-07-24, 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast your json to map and count number of keys:

```sql
WITH dataset(device_id, date, records) AS (
    values 
        ('abc', date '2021-07-24', JSON '{"1": {}, "2":{}}'),
        ('def', date '2021-07-24', JSON '{"a": {}, "b":{}, "c": {}}')
)

SELECT device_id,
    date,
    cardinality(map_keys(cast(records as MAP(VARCHAR, JSON)))) recordsNb
FROM dataset
```

Output:

| device_id | date | recordsNb |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 2021-07-24 | 2 |
| def | 2021-07-24 | 3 |

**UPD**

Since you have `ROW`s, not json values, you can try next:

```sql
SELECT device_id,
    date,
    json_array_length(cast(records as json)) recordsNb
FROM table
```

Comment: I get `cannot cast row` on my dataset.
It's a json stored in DynamoDB with key value pairs like this 
{
  "records": {
    "1598858047000": {
      "AB": 0
    },
    "1598858048000": {
      "BC": 0
    }
  }
}
I am not sure why it's not working

Comment: @QuentinDel a workaround (though not a performant one) can be to cast records to json and then to map. But not very performant one.

Comment: Cannot cast to map(varchar, json). Expected a json object, but got [ [[0E-9],[0E-9]]

Comment: Here is the data sample used
`
{
  "device_id": "aaaaaa-06c3-476f-8495-92ba9b30e9a4",
  "records": {
    "1529075406000": {
      "DS": 0
    },
    "1529060106000": {
      "DS": 0
    }
  },
  "date": "2018-06-15"
}
`

Comment: @QuentinDel sorry, my bad, forgot that rows are cast to json arrays. give me a sec

Comment: I got it working like this
SELECT device_id, date, json_array_length(cast(records as json)) count
FROM "default"
WHERE device_id = 'ec8096af-06c3-476f-8495-92ba9b30e9a4'
AND date = '2018-06-15'

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it's not working on production, 
I have 96 records, and when I do `SELECT cast(records as json) casted` on it gives me `[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]` with only 55 records for some reasons

Comment: @QuentinDel then I would recommend opening an issue on github or maybe modifying the data import so it actually is imported as string/json

Answer (score 1):

```sql
select device_id, date, count(*) as recordsNb 
from FROM "default"."table" 
group by device_id, date
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, 
Actually I would like to count the number of records "keys" from the records property for each couple of device_id/date. I have edited my question to provide more context.

Comment: What kind of data type is the record column?

Comment: In DynamoDB it's a json, but in Athena it's displayed as 
```
struct<1579560177000:struct<TD:decimal(38,9),PA:decimal(38,9),A:decimal(38,9),BD:decimal(38,9),AS:decimal(38,9),LA:decimal(38,9),FL:decimal(38,9),H:decimal(38,9),VS:decimal(38,9),DS:decimal(38,9)>,1579518772000:struct<DS:decimal(38,9)>,1579529572000:struct<DS:decimal(38,9)>,1579554776000:struct<TD:deci
        [...]     072000:struct<DS:decimal(38,9)>>
```

Comment: I actually want to count the number of root keys of this json